# "TS7030: Not all code paths return a value" vs. ESLint "no-undefined" and "no-useless return" conflict resolving

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

### Target

I understand what ESLint is not the single source of truth, and moreover, could be oppositely customized, but in this question I want one of below result:

- Resolve the conflict obeying to all mentioned rules
- Been said "In this case you can safely disable the ESLint rule ＜rule name＞　rule because ＜argumentation＞"

### Conflict description

Below code is valid and working, but I have [no-undefined](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undefined) ESLint rule violation:

```js
@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {

  public static getInstanceByReference(
    vueReference: Vue | Element | Array<Vue> | Array<Element>
  ): MyComponent | undefined {
    if (vueReference instanceof MyComponent) {
      return vueReference;
    }
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

If we delete `undefined` from `return undefined`, it will be [no-useless-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-return#disallow-redundant-return-statements-no-useless-return) rule violation:

```js
@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {

  public static getInstanceByReference(
    vueReference: Vue | Element | Array<Vue> | Array<Element>
  ): MyComponent | undefined {
    if (vueReference instanceof MyComponent) {
      return vueReference;
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

If we completely return useless from the view point of JavaScript last `return`, it will be the TypeScript error:

```
TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.
```

```js
@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {

  public static getInstanceByReference(
    vueReference: Vue | Element | Array<Vue> | Array<Element>
  ): MyComponent | undefined {
    if (vueReference instanceof MyComponent) {
      return vueReference;
    }
  }
}
```

If we change the return value signature to `MyComponent | void`, we get the [no-invalid-void-type](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-invalid-void-type.md) rule violation of [@typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint).

Comment: Last option looks to be the most sensible by far to me. This looks like a limitation of the `no-invalid-void-type` rule. If it were me, I'd disable that rule for this line.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's actually expressly the opposite of what is stated in the docs for `no-invalid-void-type`: "The void type means “nothing” or that a function does not return any value, in contrast with implicit undefined type which means that a function returns a value undefined. So “nothing” cannot be mixed with any other types, other than never, which accepts all types. If you need this - use the undefined type instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question I'd ask is "what is the goal of your code?"

If the goal is to signal an error/nothing state - then a "nullish" value is truly what you want.
Given that your lint config (for whatever reason) bans the `undefined` value, then why not just use `null`?

```
 public static getInstanceByReference(
    vueReference: Vue | Element | Array<Vue> | Array<Element>
  ): MyComponent | null {
    if (vueReference instanceof MyComponent) {
      return vueReference;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

---

If you *really* want the `undefined` value without explicitly referencing `undefined`, then as per the [`no-undefined` docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undefined), you can just use the `void` operator:

```
 public static getInstanceByReference(
    vueReference: Vue | Element | Array<Vue> | Array<Element>
  ): MyComponent | undefined {
    if (vueReference instanceof MyComponent) {
      return vueReference;
    }
    return void 0;
  }
```

---

As an aside.

> If we change the return value signature to MyComponent | void, we get the no-invalid-void-type rule violation of @typescript-eslint.

`void` should not be used in a union type. It's pretty a non-sensical type to say "this function returns something or returns absolutely nothing". It contradicts things and causes TS to act somewhat counter-intuitively (i.e. like disabling the missing return statement check).

This is why the `no-invalid-void-type` rule reports on `MyComponent | void`, and is no doubt the reason that your lint config has the rule turned on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `MyComponent | null` is optimal for my case.